# What is the correct way to recite Darood Sharif - Durood e Ibrahim?

Tags: salat, arabic, reciting

I have been listening Darood Sharif on youtube and I have notice reciter say Muhammadin and other reciter say  Muhammad.

Also reciters say Ibraheem and Ibraheema.

So for example:

Reciter One: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WW8gxrrT2tY

> Allah humma sal-li 'ala Muhammad**in**
>
> wa 'ala ali Muhammad**in**,
>
> Kama sal-layta 'ala Ibrahee**ma**
>
> Wa'ala ali Ibrahee**ma**
>
> innaka Hameedum Majeed

Reciter Two: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBkmAapKkpE

> Allah humma sal-li 'ala Muhammad**in**
>
> wa 'ala ali Muhammad,
>
> Kama sal-layta 'ala Ibraheem
>
> Wa'ala ali Ibraheema
>
> innaka Hameedum Majeed

So which is the correct way to recite Darood Sharif - Durood e Ibrahim when praying salaat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods are valid.  In Arabic, a final vowel of a word is typically dropped when you stop on it, but pronounced if you continue.  In the case of "Muhammad", it ends with a *tanwin kasra*, which is the vowel "i" (*kasra*) pronounced with nunation "n" (*tanwin*); so far as Arabic is concerned it's still a vowel even with the "n" sound.  Similarly, "Ibrahim" ends with a *fatha*, which is the vowel "a".

So if you choose to recite the *darood* while stopping at the end of each line, you would pronounce it without the final vowels (such as in your second example), but if you choose to recite the lines together in one go, you would pronounce the final vowels (such as in your first example).

On a related note, you may also find reciters will merge the *tanwin* with the *waw* if they join the first two lines, so it would effectively be pronounced "…Muhammadiwwa…" rather than "…Muhammadin wa…" (i.e. with double the length of the "w" sound while dropping the "n" sound completely).  This too is valid.